# Removing last character from WPF editable combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am using Editable Combo box

```
<ComboBox Width="200" Height="30" IsEditable="True">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="true"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="false"/>
</ComboBox>
```

1st issue: If i select true and then delete the last character 'e' then the text box has just tru but the selected Item property change is never fired, I mean the setter of the property data bind to selected item is never called.

2nd issue: If i now open the drop down and try to select true, the text in the text box remains same 'tru' it does not change to true

Vikas

Comment: That is odd. I didn't realise it worked like that. I expected that when you edit the text it would change the SelectedItem to null. I never come across this situation as I very rarely make ComboBoxes editable.

Comment: Seems to me that as long as the currently selected item starts with the content in the text box and the text box is not empty, it will not change the selected item/index/value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "adjust" the behaviour e.g. by using an attached property like this:

The behaviour will be: If the text from the `Text` property is different from the selected item's text => set selected index to -1 (this also makes selected item null etc.). Tweak to your preferences.

Note: I'm not sure if this works correctly if you bind a value to `Enable` and change this several times (memory leaks etc.). It's also hardwired to `string` items. You might need a more general apporach to be really reusable.

```
public class StrictComboxBox
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Enable", typeof (bool), typeof (StrictComboxBox), new PropertyMetadata(defaultValue: default(bool), propertyChangedCallback: EnableChanged));

    private static void EnableChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = d as ComboBox;
        if (cb == null)
            return;

        var value = GetEnable(cb);

        if (value)
        {

            DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(ComboBox.TextProperty, typeof(ComboBox))
            .AddValueChanged(cb, TextChanged);
        }
        else
        {
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(ComboBox.TextProperty, typeof(ComboBox))
            .RemoveValueChanged(cb, TextChanged);
        }

    }

    private static void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as ComboBox;

        var selectedTextMatches = cb.SelectedValue != null && ( (cb.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content as string) == cb.Text;

        if (selectedTextMatches == false)
        {
            cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

    }

    public static void SetEnable(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(EnableProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetEnable(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool) element.GetValue(EnableProperty);
    }

}
```

Usage in xaml would be:

```
<Window xmlns:my ="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.ContainingTheStrictComboBoxClass"  ...>

<ComboBox Width="200" Height="30" IsEditable="True" my:StrictComboxBox.Enable="True">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="true"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="false"/>
</ComboBox>
```